# Is it possible to upgrade the database providing metadata storage for a HDP cluster?

Tags: hadoop, metadata, hortonworks-data-platform

We have a Hadoop cluster with a very old PostgreSQL database (9.2) storing cluster metadata.
Is it possible to replace it with a more up-to-date version? I am concerned about breaking the cluster, what should I consider?

Answer (score 0):

@Luis Sisamon

My recommendation would be to dump the 9.2 database and import into the version of your new preference.  Assuming the import works without any errors,  you should be able to move from old database to the new database.   If you have concerns I would test this out with a dev cluster first before trying on live/prod system.

Comment: Thanks, problem is we have no dev cluster to test this... i am very uncomfortable messing with this.

Comment: You should be able to dump pqsl to a file and spin up a 1 node hdp dev cluster to test this...  I use vagrant/virtualbox from ambari to do this very easily.   If you can schedule full downtime for cluster,  you can easily try to move from old Postgres to new Postgres assuming the dump/import works without conflicts.  If you have issues you can just switch back to old Postgres.

Comment: yes, what scares me is the switching from one database to another on the real system. worst case we should be able to go back to the original database, I think.